# Ionic: Getting data from http calls

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to ionic so please be patient if its pretty basic question.

i am using Advance http plugin for  API calls as below

**Installation**:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http
```

Imports in app.module.ts and work file tab1.page.ts

```
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
```

Included provider in app.moudle.ts

```
 providers: [BarcodeScanner,  HTTP,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
```

**Html page**

```
  <ion-button size="large" expand="block" (click)="tcketDetails()"> Data</ion-button>
```

**TS file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BarcodeScanner,BarcodeScannerOptions} from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import {AlertController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {TicketDetailsService} from '../ticket/ticket-details.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  scannedData: any;
  qrcode_esult: any;
  picture: string;
  constructor(public alertController: AlertController,  private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,private ticekt_details: TicketDetailsService) {}
  tcketDetails(){
    alert(this.ticekt_details.get_ticket_details());
  }
 }
```

Below is my **ticket-details.service** file that gets data and returns it :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TicketDetailsService {
  private server_path = 'https://websitelink.net/dev/tickets/ticekt_details/1';
  constructor(private http: HTTP) { }

  async get_ticket_details(){
    let postedvalues = {
      'key':'value'
    };
    const optionsValue = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-API-KEY': ''
    };

    var url=this.server_path;
    return this.http.post(url, postedvalues, optionsValue).then(data => {
      var response=JSON.parse(data.data);
      return response;
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
}
```

This returns me **[object Promise]** in alert

if I hit the link in browser I get below

```
{"data":{"status":0,"message":"some message"}}
```

Can someone help me what do i have to fix here to get the message text instead

Comment: Please check this video for understanding what the promise is, I think it's explained in a super clear way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "return await" in your getDetails function ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood your question and was reading again. 
You may put your response in an object, and display it in your view with your alert,
as it is a promise due to async model...

Comment: okay, Could you please help me to sort it out i have put up such detailed question and tired myself its not working for me , Thanks

Comment: Would you do a stackblitz example so I can play with it.

Comment: In this line: return **await** this.http.post(url, postedvalues, optionsValue).then(data => {